# Android Spotify Remote SDK player state subscription called 3 times when context changes

Tags: android, spotify

I connect to the Spotify remote once, but it's as if I'm using 3-4 remotes at the same time when I invoke `remote.getPlayerApi().skipNext()`, `remote.getPlayerApi().skipPrevious()`, or `remote.getPlayerApi.play(uri)`.  The `remote.getPlayerApi().subscriptionToPlayerState()` gets invoked 3-4 times in quick succession when the above remote commands are made.

However, pause and resume works fine.  Mind you, all of this is running on a foreground service.

I tried restarting my phone, but the same deal occurs.  It's as though the old remotes that weren't properly disconnected, connect and act on the subscription callback.

For reference, [I basically did everything here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/quick-start/), plus my side of the code:

```
    // Set player state subscription to Spotify Remote SDK
    private void setupSpotifySubscriptions() {
        mSpotifyAppRemote.getPlayerApi().subscribeToPlayerState().setEventCallback(new Subscription.EventCallback<PlayerState>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(PlayerState playerState) {
                updatePlayerState(playerState);
            }
        });
    }


    // Update the player UI in Flutter
    private void updatePlayerState(PlayerState playerState) {
        HashMap<String, Object> payloadToServer = new HashMap<>();
        payloadToServer.put("position", playerState.playbackPosition);
        payloadToServer.put("duration", playerState.track.duration);
        payloadToServer.put("song_name", playerState.track.name);
        payloadToServer.put("song_artists", stringifyArtists(playerState.track.artists));
        payloadToServer.put("song_id", playerState.track.uri);
        payloadToServer.put("is_paused", playerState.isPaused);
        socket.emitToServer("player_state", payloadToServer);

    }
```

Once I connect, 3-4 messages from Spotify remote appear, making my assumption seem very plausible:

```
D/RemoteServiceIo(32686): Connecting to Spotify service
D/RemoteServiceIo(32686): Message from Spotify: [2,4,{"authid":null,"authmethod":null,"authprovider":null,"authrole":null,"roles":{"broker":{},"caller":null,"dealer":{},"subscriber":null}}]
D/RemoteServiceIo(32686): Message from Spotify: [33,1,8]
D/RemoteServiceIo(32686): Message from Spotify: [36,8,28,{},[],{"long_text":"","short_text":"","code":0}]
D/MainActivity(32686): Connected! Yay!
D/RemoteServiceIo(32686): Message from Spotify: [33,2,9]
D/RemoteServiceIo(32686): Message from Spotify: [36,9,29,{},[],{"track":{"artist":{"name":"Jesper Ryom","type":"artist","uri":"spotify:artist:6QAXPFWafsrhltnhogrQ1P"},"artists":[{"name":"Jesper Ryom","type":"artist","uri":"spotify:artist:6QAXPFWafsrhltnhogrQ1P"}],"album":{"name":"Syvsover","type":"album","uri":"spotify:album:3Se55Em2mSqYwuQLqS7XDb"},"saved":false,"duration_ms":423586,"name":"Clock","uri":"spotify:track:6N6jCOPR4kEczFBMrgun5A","image_id":"content://com.spotify.music/image/Njc5YmIzMzYyYmM5YjhlODM3ZjU3NWQzODQ4Y2I0M2JkZTVjNmM5ZQ%3D%3D%0A","is_episode":false,"is_podcast":false},"is_paused":true,"playback_speed":0.0,"playback_position":67667,"playback_options":{"shuffle":false,"repeat":0},"playback_restrictions":{"can_skip_next":true,"can_skip_prev":false,"can_repeat_track":false,"can_repeat_context":false,"can_toggle_shuffle":false,"can_seek":true}}]
```

UPDATE:

temporary fix using semaphores.  But it still would be nice to have this issue fixed.

```
private void updatePlayerState(PlayerState playerState) throws InterruptedException {
    HashMap<String, Object> payloadToServer = new HashMap<>();
    payloadToServer.put("position", playerState.playbackPosition);
    payloadToServer.put("duration", playerState.track.duration);
    payloadToServer.put("song_name", playerState.track.name);
    payloadToServer.put("song_artists", stringifyArtists(playerState.track.artists));
    payloadToServer.put("song_id", playerState.track.uri);
    payloadToServer.put("is_paused", playerState.isPaused);
    if (available.tryAcquire()) {
        socket.emitToServer("player_state", payloadToServer);
    }
}
```

Once receiving response from socket:

```
private Emitter.Listener onPlayerState = new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(Object... args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("[onPlayerState] " + args[0].toString());
            HashMap<String, Object> playerState = new ObjectMapper().readValue(args[0].toString(), HashMap.class);
            methodChannel.invokeMethod(SPOTIFY + PLAYER_STATE, playerState);
            if(player_state.get("song_id") != playerState.get("song_id")){
                methodChannel.invokeMethod(POP_USER_QUEUE, playerState.get("song_id"));
                popUserQueue((String) playerState.get("song_id"));
            }
            player_state = playerState;
            releaseSemaphore();
        } catch (java.lang.Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
};

private void releaseSemaphore(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            available.release();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's as if I'm using 3 remotes at the same time when I invoke remote.getPlayerApi().skipNext() or remote.getPlayerApi.play(uri)"? Looking at your code, I'm guessing `socket` goes to some other machine? If so, you should keep in mind how enthusiastically Android starts and stops activities. It's a bit surprising at first, but the flowchart towards the top of [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) is pretty clear. Depending on what you're doing, you may want/need to move your spotify code from and activity to a service.

Comment: Yeah, i forgot to mention that all of this is running on a foreground service.  When i mean running on 3 remotes, I mean the subscription callback gets invoked 3 times in quick succession.  I wrote this pretty late at night and I realize now that it doesn't make any sense the way I did.  Edited the post ^